# With .OrderBy not working in DataGridView in Visual Basic Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, datagridview, sql-order-by

The following code I'm using straight from the textbook however it's not sorting by last name.
I saw other questions and they didn't apply to visual basic.

```
' load players table and order by last name, then first 
    With dbcontext.Players
        .OrderBy(Function(Player) Player.LastName)
        .ThenBy(Function(Player) Player.FirstName)
        .Load()
    End With
```

the output looks like:

```
1   John    Red 0.375
2   Jack    Blue    0.223
3   George  Green   0.344
```

but in a DataGridView (won't let me paste a pic here)
I've tried changing the Data Entity key but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a query. You must assign it to a variable or it does nothing. The With block only allows you to use the `.{Properties/methods}` of an object without calling the object name each time. It does not provide a variable that receives these commands.

```
Dim query = dbcontext.Players
           .OrderBy(Function(Player) Player.LastName)
           .ThenBy(Function(Player) Player.FirstName)
```

Comment: Well that depends on what Load() does, but OP does need to provide that info!

Comment: How so? There is no variable to hold anything.

Comment: Load() gets a IEnumerable as its 'this' input and could (say) ToArray that input and place in a static field, or set it as the data source for a singleton datagridview, or throw an error if some .Any condition is matched or really do anything (modulo what it can reference). Not saying it does mind

Comment: The fact that the OP says it's not working tells me @OneFineDay is correct.

Comment: What is `dbcontext` anyway??  The DataGridView doesn't appear to have a `.Load()` method according to MSDN.

Comment: It should be the entity model and `Players` is a representation of the `Player` table from the database.